# kafka different topics set different partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, apache-zookeeper

As I know, 'num.partitions' in kafka server.properties will be worked for all topics.
Now I want to set partitionNumber=1 for topicA and partitionNumber=2 for topicB.
Is that possible to implementation with high level api?

Comment: So you're trying to create the topics through the API rather than through the command line scripts as shown in the quickstart? http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart

Comment: yes.I want to set the partitions for topic with api. Any idea for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num.partitions` is a value used when a topic is generated automatically. If you generate a topic yourself, you can set any number of partitions as you want.

You can generate a topic yourself with the following command. (replication factor 3 and the number of partitions 2. Capital words are what you have to replace.)

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper ZOOKEEPER_HOSTNAME:ZOOKEEPER_PORT \
--replication-factor 3 --partitions 2 --topic TOPIC_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

There a configuration value that can be set on a Kafka Broker.

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

True is actually the default setting,

> Enable auto creation of topic on the server. If this is set to true then attempts to produce data or fetch metadata for a non-existent topic will automatically create it with the default replication factor and number of partitions.

So if you read or write from a non-existent partition as if it existed, if will automatically create one for you. I've never heard of using the high level api to automatically create one.

Looking over the [Kafka Protocol Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol), there doesn't seem to be a provided way to create topics.

Comment: Thanks.How about the low level api? Create topic with partitions manually?

Comment: So both the high level and low level api implement the Protocol Documentation that I listed above. So there doesn't seem a way to create a topic through either of the APIs. You've would either have to explicitly create it with a command like Heejin's answer, or setup your default configuration and enable auto topic creation like I said in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That means if I want to  create two  topics with different partitions.I have to use command line script.